# Why can I get very few data with Rfacebook?

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's use birthdays as an example:

I'm using Rfacebook and I seem to get a lot more data through the direct api available here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ than what I get in R.

In R, I only get the user id and the name, all the 13 other fields are NA. In the developper tool I get the birthday etc. but not in R

**My code in R:**

```
library(Rfacebook)
mytoken <- fbOAuth(app_id = theAppID, app_secret = 'TheAppSecret', extended_permissions = T)
save(mytoken, file='fbtoken')
load('fbtoken')
me <-getUsers('me', token=mytoken, private_info = T)
me$username
```

I've gone in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  and I've done Get Token -> Get User Access Token for my app, but it does not seem to have changed anything.

Why don't I get the birthday data via R?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to specify the fields that you want.

Comment: Edited to take the example of the birthday, thanks!

Comment: In your code you need to specify which fields you want. You only get back the fields you ask for and if you don't ask for any fields you will get the default ones